# React Firebase on refresh rdirects to login then to home page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

User is authorized. On refresh page path is reset and redirects to "/login" and then to "/".
Also I can’t get to the page by typing the url. The same thing happens.

App.js:

```
<div className="wrapper">
   {app.auth().currentUser != null ?
      (  
         <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
               <div>
                  <Switch>
                     <div className="wrapper">
                        <Route path="/" render={MainComponent} />    
                     </div>
                  </Switch>
               </div>
            </Router>
         </AuthProvider>
      ) : (
         <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
               <div>
                  <Switch>
                     <div className="wrapper">
                        <Route path="/login" exact render={LoginComponent} />
                        <Route path="/signup" exact component={SignUpComponent} />
                        <Route path="/forgetpass" exact render={ForgetPassComponent} />
                        <Redirect from='*' to='/login' />
                     </div>
                  </Switch>
               </div>
            </Router>
         </AuthProvider>
      )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing the ternary like you have done, use a private/protected route instead?

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return app.auth().currentUser ? <Component /> : <Redirect from="" to="/login" noThrow />
}

              <Switch>
                 <div className="wrapper">
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/" render={MainComponent} />    
                    <Route path="/login" exact render={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/signup" exact component={SignUpComponent} />
                    <Route path="/forgetpass" exact render={ForgetPassComponent} />
                    <Redirect from='*' to='/login' />
                 </div>
              </Switch>
```

then that way you may not see the redirect happening like you are. if you are I would recommend storing it in `localStorage` and then reading from that instead. I was getting a flicker before when I use `onAuthStateChange` from firebase on its own. but when used in conjunction with `localstorage` it was fine. I think that's what you're getting when you say "On refresh page path is reset and redirects to "/login" and then to "/" "

Comment: I don't use private/protected because I had problems with rendering, which I could only solve in this way, and besides, this problem was still when I used private.
So you mean that I have to verify authentication with `localalstorage`, having put `onAuthStateChange` there before, do I understand correctly? Could you give an example or give a link with information, that would be great